# Accessing xaml grid.column from backend/positioning elements

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

```XAML
<Grid x:Name="gv">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <TextBlock x:Name="aaa" Text="asd" Height="40" Grid.Column="0"/>
</Grid>
```

So basically I created an element in the backend and want to add it to the gv grid to column 1, how should I do that ?

```C#
TextBlock frName = new TextBlock();
frName.Text = "123";
gv.Children.Add(frName);
```

In xaml it would look like that i guess

```XAML
<TextBlock Text="123" Height="40" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

I can't find any property or any note in documentation what is responsible for how to place in desired column.

Ps.

I'm creating Grid Column definitions as well in backend but I found it rly easy how to do it, not sure if I do it in the good way.

```C#
Grid tg = new Grid();
GridLength cw = new GridLength(70); 
ColumnDefinition cd;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    cd = new ColumnDefinition();
    cd.Width = cw;
    tg.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);
}
```

Comment: Found the solution here, hope it helps someone and makes less stress :D http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9a11a66-f5f9-4fb0-a7ad-603956bcc4e8/accessing-a-gridrow-and-gridcolumn-at-runtime?forum=silverlightnet

Answer (score 1):

[Grid.Row](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.rowproperty.aspx) and [Grid.Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.columnproperty.aspx) (and Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top) are attached properties. They are declared by the container class ([Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.aspx) or Canvas), not by the DependencyObject they are set on. See the [Attached properties overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758282.aspx) on MSDN.

To set an attached property in code use the [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.setvalue.aspx) method with the identifier of the property. [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.getvalue.aspx) will return the property.

```
frName.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty,1);
```

Your code to create the Grid and its columns is essentially correct. You'll still need to add it to a container in your visual tree similar to how you add frName with gv.Children.Add(frName)

Comment: Anoter way is to do it via utility method [Grid.SetColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.setcolumn) - `Grid.SetColumn(frName, 1);`